# Ek! There's a missing left angle bracket on the ask-advice page!

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

Note that this is a very minor issue so it does not deserve an Eeeek, not even an Eek, [just an Ek](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/693228#693228).

On the mobile site, I see this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice (click image to enlarge):

[image]

`h2>Be on-topic`? I think you're missing a `<` there.

(a margin would also be nice so the letters aren't squished to the side of the screen, but that's even more minor than this :P)

Comment: Ek is pronounced [ek]. Eeeek is pronounced [ēk] (a long e)

Comment: A margin? Ugh, no. Those devices are small enough as it is, I don't want to waste a pixel of screen estate.

Comment: @Cole so maybe "ick"? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [ik] might work

Comment: @Gilles even worse, on a retina device, it's _two_ pixels! **TWO** WHOLE PIXELS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this should be fixed in the next build.